# If Cell Contains Text Then Copy to Another Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to copy a collumn on to another excel sheet where the first cell starts with: "Not Found"

If a cell in the first collumns contains "Not Found" I want to display them filtered in my First sheet (Stats Aug..).
in A36

I've tried to use the VBA script below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4swMZe0TEE

If you wants to see my full excel sheet url can be found here:

https://we.tl/t-7JKgk7uX7q?src=dnl

I need a script that when I hit a "Not Found" button I get all not found descriptions, number and created by's on my Stats Aug.2021

So this one is filtered manually on not found : [Problems Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUJ9U.png)
But I Need a button that filters this automatically and displays it in this sheet: [Stats_aug.2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru8A9.png)

[Problems Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUJ9U.png) is replaced every month. But it will be helpfull if I have button who filters this automaticly on "Not found" and places this in
[Stats_aug.2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru8A9.png)

Hope this is more clear...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So I have an excel sheet where I want to place a filtered table. The table that I want filtered in the sheet must be filtered on text that contains  “Not Found”

Comment: The second URL, it is not clearly, could you provide the screenshot about the sheet???

Comment: When you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1671636/edit), upload the image to http://imgur.com and link to it, someone with enough reputation will likely embed it for you

Comment: Many people will not download files from unknown sources. Including all information will also make sure your question remains relevant in the future, when that link will most likely be dead

Comment: Additional info has been added. Many thanks in advance to the person who wants to help me out here..